# android edittext with drop down list

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext which gets values from the user. I want to add an option which allows the user to choose from different options via drop down list when edittext is clicked. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

This is edittext code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/dish_quantity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dish_name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Quantity" />
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: that is called AutoCompleteTextView in android

Answer (score 29):

I think this is your requirement:

just follow this example:
**Xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >   
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/languages"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></AutoCompleteTextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity:-**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] languages = { "C","C++","Java","C#","PHP","JavaScript","jQuery","AJAX","JSON" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                //Create Array Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, languages);
                //Find TextView control
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.languages);
        //Set the number of characters the user must type before the drop down list is shown
                acTextView.setThreshold(1);
                //Set the adapter
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Demo:-**

[image]

Comment: i just dont want to type in the edittext i want to get on value from list when i click on edit text this list will open .is any way to do this

Comment: First of all your date picker is not a edittext,os why you want edit text drop down.

Comment: Use PopUp Menu by creating a menu which contains your items and then inflate the menu in main activity then override `onMenuItemClick` and by using a switch statement on different id of your items you can set the `EditText` view as as you wish. Hope you get my explanation

Answer (score 7):

I think what you are looking for can be done with a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) instead of an  EditText.

Here's [a detailed explanation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) of how to use it.

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"  
        android:text="@string/what_is_your_favourite_programming_language_" />  

    <AutoCompleteTextView  
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"  
        android:ems="10"  
        android:text="">  

        <requestFocus />  
    </AutoCompleteTextView>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.graphics.Color;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    String[] language ={"C","C++","Java",".NET","iPhone","Android","ASP.NET","PHP"};  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of language names  
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
            (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,language);  
        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView  
           AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);  
           actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character  
           actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView  
           actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);  

    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
        return true;  
    }  

}
```

Comment: no its not autocompletetextview in list view like only selected value are there

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you want user to edit the content even after selecting the item?

Comment: when i click on edittext it show list like month shown in picture.

Comment: That one actually works very well if you want to add e.g. trailing clear text icon or smth. Very nice one !

Answer (score 4):

On Android it`s called autocompletetextview

Official Google doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Please check this out,tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Answer (score 0):

I find a way with MaterialAutoCompleteTextView inside TextInputLayout. Just set TextInputLayout's endIconMode to "dropdown_menu" and set ArrayAdapter to AutoCompleteTextView.

```xml
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_module"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/et_module"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="module"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="text" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```